# How to fix missing return in function in swift but function does return

Tags: swift, function

So I have a function used in both macOS and iOS however when I Switch it to the iOS scheme I get a error that says missing return in function expacted to return image.
However when on the macOS scheme it work perfectly.

Here is my Code

```
    var image: Image {
        if isStringLink(string: imageName) {
            print("Loading Image from URL")
            if var imageNameLink = URL(string: imageName) {
                var imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageNameLink)
                guard var UIImageResult = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                    print("Failed to set image result\n\n Loading Image from Bundle")
                    #if os(iOS)
                    Image(imageName)
                    return Image(imageName)
                    #endif
                    #if os(macOS)
                    return Image(imageName)
                    #endif
                }
                print("Returning Image")
                #if os(iOS)
                Image(uiImage: UIImageResult)
                #endif
                #if os(macOS)
                return Image(nsImage: UIImageResult)
                #endif
            } else {
                print("Loading Image from Bundle")
                #if os(iOS)
                Image(imageName)
                #endif
                #if os(macOS)
                return Image(imageName)
                #endif
            }
        } else {
            print("Loading Image from Bundle")
            #if os(iOS)
            Image(imageName)
            #endif
            #if os(macOS)
            return Image(imageName)
            #endif
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's twice, but you have `#if os(iOS) Image(imageName) #endif #if os(macOS) return Image(imageName) #endif`. Why put a return if macOS but not iOS? Once you answered that, you'll know ;)

Comment: You have so many `#if os` here that you should seriously consider factoring out two separate functions here, one for iOS and one for macOS

Comment: Unrelated, but I hope that the "URL" is not a Web URL, but a local file URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for macOS?
Let's remove the noise of the `#if`.

You can copy/paste, and comment the previous one.
We'll then keep only the code that's failing, the one inside the `#if os(iOS)` and remove the code for `#if os(macOS)`

```
var image: Image {
        if isStringLink(string: imageName) {
            print("Loading Image from URL")
            if var imageNameLink = URL(string: imageName) {
                var imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageNameLink)
                guard var UIImageResult = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                    print("Failed to set image result\n\n Loading Image from Bundle")
                    Image(imageName) //**
                    return Image(imageName)
                }
                print("Returning Image")
                Image(uiImage: UIImageResult) //HERE
            } else {
                print("Loading Image from Bundle")
                Image(imageName) // HERE
            }
        } else {
            print("Loading Image from Bundle")
            Image(imageName) // HERE
        }
    }
```

You are not using `return` in the last 3 times (marked with `//HERE`), but you were returning something in case of macOS. Why should there be a difference?
Write `return` before it. Also there is a `Image(imageName)` before a `return` (marked with `//**`) which seems to be useless.

In the end:

```
var image: Image {
    if isStringLink(string: imageName) {
        print("Loading Image from URL")
        if var imageNameLink = URL(string: imageName) {
            var imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageNameLink)
            guard var UIImageResult = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                print("Failed to set image result\n\n Loading Image from Bundle")
                #if os(iOS)
                return Image(imageName)
                #endif
                #if os(macOS)
                return Image(imageName)
                #endif
            }
            print("Returning Image")
            #if os(iOS)
            return Image(uiImage: UIImageResult)
            #endif
            #if os(macOS)
            return Image(nsImage: UIImageResult)
            #endif
        } else {
            print("Loading Image from Bundle")
            #if os(iOS)
            return Image(imageName)
            #endif
            #if os(macOS)
            return Image(imageName)
            #endif
        }
    } else {
        print("Loading Image from Bundle")
        #if os(iOS)
        return Image(imageName)
        #endif
        #if os(macOS)
        return Image(imageName)
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and now it still gives me the return error and a new error that says " 'guard' body must not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw' to exit the scope "

Comment: Ah, that's because iOS/macOS, that's not all the cases? If you don't use for other platforms, you use a `fatalError("Unsupported platform")` when needed.